# Can you give an example of function $F: N → P(R)$, such that $F(n) = R\space ∀n ∈ N$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I don't fully understand the meaning of the following underlined explanation. Can you give an example of function $F: N → P(R)$ such that $F(n) = R\space ∀n ∈ N$?

> **Definition**
>   A family of sets is a function $F$ from an index set $I$ to some range set. Intuitively we consider {$F(i): i \in I$} to be the family of sets.
>
> It should be noted that a family is distinct from a set of sets, since a set may be repeated in a family, but can count only once as an element of a set. 
>   $\underline {\text{For example, the function}\space F\space \text{from}\space N\space to \space P(R),\space \text{such that} F(n) = R}$ $\underline {\space \text{for every} \space n\in N,\text{is a family, but} \{F(n): n\in N\}}$ $\underline {\text{as a set has precisely one element}}$.
>   Source: Numbers, Sets and Axioms: The Apparatus of Mathematics, A. G. Hamilton, p.132

[added]

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two nonempty sets and let $b$ be a fixed element of $Y$. The relation
>   $$C_b=\{(x, b) | x \in X\}$$
>   gives rise to the function $C_b : X \rightarrow Y$ given by $C_b(x) = b$ for all $x$ in $X$. The function $C_b$ is called a constant function.
>   Source: Set Theory by You-Feng Lin, Shwu-Yeng T. Lin.

Comment: You’ve just given the example yourself: define $F(n)=R$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. That is, $F$ is a constant function whose value at each $n\in\Bbb N$ is the set $R$. If you were now to form the Cartesian product $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}F(n)$, for instance, you’d have $R\times R\times R\times\ldots=R^{\Bbb N}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If R={1, 2, 3,. ..}, then does it mean when $n \in N$, F(n) = 1, F(n) = 2, F(n) = 3 ...?

Comment: No, it means $F(1) = \{1,2,3, ...\}, F(2) = \{1,2,3, ...\}, F(3) = \{1,2,3,...\}$ etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna give you the names of five celebrities.  The first name is Michael Jackson.  The second name is Michael Jackson.  The third name is Michael Jackson.  The fourth name is Michael Jackson.  The fifth name is Michael Jackson.

How many names have I given you?

In one sense, I have given you five names: to each number $n$ between $1$ and $5$, I have associated a celebrity's name.  In other words, I have defined a function from $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to the set $S$ of all celebrity names.

In another sense, I have given you only name.  If you think of what I gave you as a set whose elements are names of celebrities, then that set only has one element in it.  That is, if instead of the function itself which I described in the previous paragraph, you only consider the range of that function.  By the 'range' of a function, I mean the set of all possible outputs.

---

If $R$ is a set, $P(R)$ is the set of all subsets of $R$.  For example, if $R = \{1,2\}$, then $P(R) = \{ \emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{1,2\}\}$, where $\emptyset$ is the empty set.

Considering $R = \{1,2\}$, we have the function $F: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow P(R)$ (whose inputs are natural numbers, and whose outputs are elements of $P(R)$, i.e. one of the four sets $\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\},$ or $R$), given by $F(1) = \{1,2\}, F(2) = \{1,2\}, ... , F(n) = \{1,2\}$ and so on for all $n$.  I have just given you a well defined function.

The author's point was that "$F$ the function" is a different thing from "The range of $F$" (the range of $F$ being $\{\{1,2\} \}$), **not** because we care that much about the domain, but because in the former case we are counting $\{1,2\}$ over and over again, once for each natural number, and in the latter we are only counting it once.  This is the same situation as the celebrity example.